# how to dereferenze a void* as array of void*

Tags: c, arrays, struct, void-pointers

i want to build a structure which can hold simple datatypes like integers or arrays of that structure.

the structure looks like that:

```
typedef struct data_s {
  size_t size;  // size of memory data is pointing to
  void * data;  // pointer to data (array of data_t or simple type)
} data_t;
```

i have simplified it, normally there are more informations stored in the structure.
i wrote functions to set and get integer values, they work!
now i tried to write functions for creating an array and seting and getting the values, they don't work.
i used gdb to find where it fails. it shows me that my dereferencing doesnt work as i expect. i use following:

```
((data_t**)(data->data))[i]
```

and there i got a access violation.

i t would be great if somebody could show me my mistake. here is a working codeexample, i have minimized the code, that you dont have the overhead of my programm (also errorhandling is removed).

the code compiles without any error using `gcc -g main.c -o test` with gcc 4.8.1 on xubuntu 13.10 with 3.11 kernel

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct data_s {
  size_t size;
  void * data;
} data_t;

void set_integer(data_t *data, int value){
  data->size = sizeof(int);
  data->data = malloc(data->size);
  *((int*)(data->data)) = value;
}

void get_integer(data_t *data, int *value){
  (*value) = *((int*)(data->data));
}

void create_array(data_t *data, size_t len){
  data->size = sizeof(data_t) * len;
  data->data = malloc(data->size);
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<data->size; i++){ //initialize array
    ((data_t**)(data->data))[i]->data = NULL;  
    ((data_t**)(data->data))[i]->size = 0;
  }
}

void set_array(data_t *data, int index, data_t *value){
  ((data_t**)(data->data))[index]->data = value->data;
  ((data_t**)(data->data))[index]->size = value->size;
}

void get_array(data_t *data, int index, data_t *value){
  value->data = ((data_t**)(data->data))[index]->data;
  value->size = ((data_t**)(data->data))[index]->size;
}

void free_data(data_t *data, int is_array){
  if(is_array){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<(data->size / sizeof(data_t)); i++)
      free(((data_t**)(data->data))[i]->data);
  }
  free(data->data);
}

int main(int argc, char**argv){

  data_t data;
  set_integer(&data, 42);
  int val;
  get_integer(&data, &val);
  printf("expect 42; has: %d\n", val);
  free_data(&data, 0);

  data_t element;
  create_array(&data, 3);
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<3; i++){
    set_integer(&element, i*2);
    set_array(&data, i, &element);
  }
  for(i=0; i<3; i++){
    get_array(&data, i, &element);
    get_integer(&element, &val);
    printf("index: %d; value: %d\n", i, val);
  }
  free_data(&data, 1);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You added to the confusion by naming the struct member and struct variable both as `data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does `data->data` point to? Well, the line `data->data = malloc(data->size);` tells you: it points to a slap of uninitialized  memory.

The problem is, that you don't store anything in that memory before trying to dereference a pointer you read from this memory. I. e. `(data_t**)data->data` is fine, `((data_t**)data->data)[index]` yields a `data_t*` of *undefined value*, and because that value is undefined, dereferencing the pointer with `((data_t**)data->data)[index]->data` is undefined behavior.

If you want to create an array of `data_t` objects, one indirection suffices, i. e. use

```
void create_array(data_t *data, size_t len){
  data->size = sizeof(data_t) * len;
  data->data = malloc(data->size);
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<data->size; i++){ //initialize array
    ((data_t*)(data->data))[i].data = NULL;  
    ((data_t*)(data->data))[i].size = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`((data_t**)(data->data))[i]` is used when data->data is an array of pointers, try

```
((data_t*)(data->data))[i]
```

**EDIT**: to access the members, use something like

```
((data_t*)data->data)[i].data = NULL;
((data_t*)data->data)[i].size = 0;
```

Comment: it doesnt compile because then i cant access it as an arry anymore, it has to be something like ** i guess

Comment: I've added additional code to access the struct variables, hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
((data_t**)(data->data))[i];
```

In the above statement, `data->data` evaluates to `data` member of structure variable `data` (you should use different identifiers) which is of type `void *`. Now, you want to point `data->data` to a buffer which is an array of objects of type `data_t`. This means you must cast `data->data` to type `data_t *`, and not `data_t **`. Therefore, you should change the above statement to

```
((data_t *)(data->data))[i];
```

everywhere in your code. Also, note that `free` takes an argument of type `void *` and therefore you don't need to cast your pointer before passing it to `free`.

Comment: @cmaster true. I am talking about type of `data->data` which is `void *`.